# Referencing class library in inline vb code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reference, .net-assembly, inline-code

I'm working on a legacy vb.net application that does most of its work using inline code (

Within that script I need to access functions from a third party .net dll.

The dll(s) themself are stored in the GAC.

Before I started the page looked something like the following

```
<script runat="server">    
    Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        '''code here    
    End Sub
</script>
```

For instance say the dll is called Foo.dll and I need to access the Bar class and the .Run() method

ie.

```
<script runat="server">    
    Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim bar as Foo.Bar = new Foo.Bar()
        bar.Run()
    End Sub
</script>
```

I have tried to reference the dlls using

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Foo" %>
```

in the same place as the other imports however I receive the following

> error BC30002: Type 'Foo.Bar' is not defined

Is there some other way I should be refering this third party dll, I'm mostly a C# guy and haven't dealt much with VB or this kind of inline code. Note the code I have shown is all from a user control (.ascx)

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you working in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Foo, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sfgfdsgfdsgsdg" %>
```

as it was in the gac and not being automatically referenced

Answer (score 0):

You have added a reference to the assembly, correct?  You do have to have a reference to the 3rd party assemblies before you can use the Imports statements with their namespaces.

If you want to try to create the object without a direct reference to the dlls you could try the [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5%28vs.71%29.aspx) method. But I suspect a better answer would be to get the references working correctly so that you don't need the CreateObject method.